# Design issue- should use seperate thread for GUI?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I'm building a little software in Java, with a GUI.
I have an algorithm which runs continuously (Almost 24/7) (I have a stop/start button in GUI)
This algorithm should update a list and show a log on the GUI.
The question is- should I create a separate class or thread for this procedure (algorithm),
1) If the answer is yes - Should I transfer the GUI elements that I should update as parameters to that procedure? Would it cause problems updating the GUI?
2) If not - how should I design it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using (framework/lib) to build ui in your application?

Answer (score 3):

You should use for heavy task `SwingWorker`, is designed for this situations. Here you have a nice article [why do we need SwingWorker?](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/).
You need this cause if your algorithm take for example 5 secs and you run in the same thread as gui, it's gonna to freeze your view until finish.

BTW all gui-components must be updated in the `Event Dispatch Thread`, so you don't have to update them in another thread cause they don't be updated.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is- should I create a separate class or thread for this
>   procedure (algorithm),

Yes, this is a common practice to do so.

> Should I transfer the GUI elements that I should update as parameters
>   to that procedure? Would it cause problems updating the GUI?

You do not really required to pass anything. The only thing you need to enure is that all interactions with ui elements are done within ui thread (to avoid concurrency issues). Usually this is done by creating runnable that does ui-related job and passing it to UI framework you are using to be scheduled in ui thread.